# Volume of pipe using weighted centerline

Tags: calculus, volume

This is a problem in my subject Calculus.

Let $E\subset\mathbb R^3$ be a pipe and $\gamma$ is its mass centerline (or weighted centerline, I have no clue what it's called in English, sorry for my bad). It means every (plane section $D_p$ of $E$ which is perpendicular to $\gamma$ at $p$) takes $p$ as its mass center (I don't know if it is called weighted center, weighted centroid or whatever, this is what I translated from my language so).

Suppose $\gamma$ is reparametrized by arclength and $\gamma''(s)\ne0\ \ \forall s$. Let
$$T=\gamma',\ \ N=\frac{1}{\|T'\|}T',\ \ B=T\times N.$$

The problem start with finding det$J_\varphi(u,v,s)$ where
$$\varphi(u,v,s)=\gamma(s)+uN+vB.$$

The next requirement is to show that if the area of $D_p$ is small enough then the volume of $E$ is given by
$$|E|=\intop_\gamma |D_p|\,ds.$$

I have tried to calculate the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$, but when I wrote out the coordinates of $\varphi$, this what I got
\begin{align}
\varphi(u,v,s)=\begin{bmatrix}x(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\|T'\|}x''(s)+\frac{v}{\|T'\|}\big(z''(s)y'(s)-z'(s)y''(s)\big) 
\\ y(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\|T'\|}y''(s)+\frac{v}{\|T'\|}\big(x''(s)z'(s)-x'(s)z''(s)\big)      
\\ z(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\|T'\|}z''(s)+\frac{v}{\|T'\|}\big(y''(s)x'(s)-y'(s)x''(s)\big)  
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I immediately realized that maybe the Jacobian matrix shouldn't be evaluated this way. And then I got stucked finding the better way.

May you help me out ? Any help is precious. Thank you much.

Comment: "center of mass" is the usual English terminology. Though in a constant gravitational field (which we generally assume to be the case, unless the objects are so large that the curvature of the Earth has a measurable affect), the center of mass and the center of gravity are the same. So we more commonly call it the center of gravity. But your original description of "mass centerline" is also acceptable, especially since you are talking about a curve, rather than a single point.